# ssh into a Win 11 PC: Authentication refused, Failed publickey

Tags: ssh, powershell, windows-11, openssh

I mean to ssh from a Win 10 + msys2 client (PC1) to a Win 11 + OpenSSH server (PC2).
I followed the usual procedure in PC2 to enable OpenSSH server, via Powershell (as I have successfully done before, albeit with Win 10 servers).

In PC1 I have added `server2` to `~/.ssh/config`, with key `/home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b`.
In PC2 I have added the contents of the matching key `id_ed25519b.pub` to `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` and `C:\Users\user2\.ssh\authorized_keys`. There are other keys that I added to try (as messages below show), but that is irrelevant.
Then,

```
[PC1]$ ssh -v server2 -i /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/USER1/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/USER1/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/USER1/.ssh/config line 15: Applying options for server2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to <ip PC2> [<ip PC2>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b type -1
debug1: identity file /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <ip PC2>:22 as 'user2'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:********************************************
debug1: Host '<ip PC2>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/USER1/.ssh/known_hosts:47
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b  explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa  explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
===================================================================  START MODIFIED
debug1: Trying private key: /home/USER1/.ssh/id_ed25519b                 <---- **** THIS SHOULD HAVE WORKED ****
===================================================================  END MODIFIED
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for key '/home/USER1/.ssh/id_rsa': <Ctrl>+C
```

The only two points that I think might help (and I am not sure how to dig further) are:

1. I am not sure if file/directory permissions may be an issue.
   I don't recall having to do anything special in previous similar configurations for Win 10.
   I know `~/.ssh` and other files need specific permissions, and I have done such configuration in Linux many times.
2. In PC2 I opened an admin PS5.1 prompt.
   Following [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Troubleshooting-Steps) I did

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Stop-Service sshd
    PS C:\Windows\system32> sshd.exe -d
```

to see debugging messages in the server. Essentially, I get `Authetication refused. Failed publickey...` This is the whole output.

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> sshd.exe -d
    debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
    debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
    debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:***************************************
    debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:***************************************
    debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:***************************************
    debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
    debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
    debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
    Server listening on :: port 22.
    debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
    Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
    Connection from <ip PC1> port 52107 on <ip PC2> port 22
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
    debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
    debug1: KEX done [preauth]
    debug1: userauth-request for user user2 service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
    debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
    debug1: user user2 matched group list administrators at line 87
    debug1: userauth-request for user user2 service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
    debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
    debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
    Authentication refused.
    Failed publickey for user2 from <ip PC1> port 52107 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:***************************************
    Connection closed by authenticating user user2 <ip PC1> port 52107 [preauth]
    debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
    debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
    debug1: do_cleanup
    debug1: Killing privsep child 20400
```

**Related**:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration
2. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09ef4533-243e-4fa1-b2ca-bcbcc08d0f1e/windows-10-pro-openssh-server-permission-denied?forum=win10itprogeneral
3. https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Logging-Facilities
4. https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Security-protection-of-various-files-in-Win32-OpenSSH
5. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/109609/unable-to-access-the-win10-pc-with-openssh-install.html

Comment: The key can only be read and accessed by the owner of the key.  Make sure that is the case.  Likewise, provide us with the OpenSSH Server configuration file. [Edit] your question instead of attempting to provide that information in a comment

Comment: @Ramhound - "The key can only be read and accessed by the owner of the key."
Am I not doing that?
Where do you see it?
How should I fix that?
I will shortly post the OpenSSH Server configuration file.

Comment: You have to modify the permissions so ONLY the Windows user can access and read the key.  I have no way of knowing if you have modified the permission on the key.  You are using the built-in OpenSSH capabilities within Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound - It appears the problem is not with the key authentication, but with authentication itself... I will post another question.

Comment: You are incorrect. Key authentication itself is failing.  This is how I know that is the case: **Failed publickey for ...**  I seem to recall there is a problem with `__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys` in the default configuration of OpenSSH on Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound - I know. But when I try to login without using the keys, I cannot either. So I suspect there is yet another problem (which I don't know it is in series or in parallel with the key issue).
It is reported [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1741025/ssh-into-a-win-11-pc-failed-password).

Comment: You not being able to login without the keys could be answered by providing the OpenSSH server configuration file.  Additionally, I would need to know the syntax your using, to make the SSH connection.  Windows username syntax can be tricky if you are not talking to a domain machine and/or you are but perhaps it's a different user.  In other words I wouldn't submit another question till you provide more information to ths one.